# A regular on / off switch AND a momentary one

Tags: switches

I'm building a drill press and I'd like to be able to turn it on with a momentary switch on the handle, but sometimes I need both my hands free while it's running. Ideally, I'd use a "lockable" momentary switch if I could find one, or even build one (ideas welcome) but so far no luck. So what I have now is :

- A wall outlet to plug the drill in ;
- A regular on/off switch ;
- A momentary switch (the - big - PCB type)
- A small 3-way toggle switch (to toggle between momentary and on / off, and yes I know it sounds clumsy and somehow counterintuitive) and ;
- A mosfet module to connect the switch(es) but I'm not sure they're of the right type / voltage, I use them in my 12V builds, should I use a different module for alternative current?

The only thing left is the diagram... How would I go and wire this ?

Comment: To latch the momentary switch you'll need a relay with a spare contact to form the latch. Have you got one?

Comment: @Transistor I'm pretty sure I haven't ; can you please post a link to some info about it, like pics and specs? Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: Craigslist -> actual drill press -> done.  You'll spend twice as much trying to hork-a-dork it this way. Also you're playing with mains power, why do that when you don't have to?    Also, when using a drill press, one hand is on the plunge bar, and the other hand is on the oil can. There's no holding a switch; to stop it just raise the plunge bar.  Or a foot pedal would do.

Comment: There are slide switches available with ON-OFF-MOM positions. Whether they're available for the ratings you need, I don't know.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, if you're working wood, you usually don't use an oil can.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that using a 12V= relay and a foot switch.

[image]

The control is to be housed in a protective enclosure with a socket for the power tool and one for the foot switch.

The foot switch is to be housed in its own enclosure and located on the floor.